# How to update existing state's any value on textInput?

Tags: react-native

I have a page that includes 5 text inputs and I try to update this variable on a form.

***Here my State:***

```
  const addressDetails = {
    country: '',
    city: '',
    town: '',
    neighborhood:'',
    street:'',
    };
  const [address,setAddress] = useState(addressDetails);
```

I prepare my state like this before sending to form:

```
        setAddress({...address,
          country:"country1",
          city:"city1",
          town:"town1",
          neighborhood:"neighborhood1",
          street:"street1"
        });
```

In my text input it looks like this:

When I try to update with equal It doesn't update.

```
      <TextInput
      label="il"
      value={address.city}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => address.city = text}
      />
          <TextInput
      label="ilçe"
      value={address.town}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => address.town = text}
      />
          <TextInput
      label="Mahalle"
      value={address.neighborhood}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => address.neighborhood = text}
      />
      <TextInput
      label="Sokak"
      value={address.street}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChange={(text) => address.street = text}
      />
```

I also try with set:

```
        <TextInput
      label="Adres Başlığı"
      value={address_header.value}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => setAdressHeader({value:text})}
      />
      <TextInput
      label="il"
      value={address.city}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => setAddress({city:text})}
      />
          <TextInput
      label="ilçe"
      value={address.town}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => setAddress({town:text})}
      />
          <TextInput
      label="Mahalle"
      value={address.neighborhood}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChangeText={(text) => setAddress({neighborhood:text})}
      />
      <TextInput
      label="Sokak"
      value={address.street}
      style={styles.textInputStyle} 
      onChange={(text) => setAddress({street:text})}
      />
```

In this situation, it just creates a new one with one variable.

I just want to update what I change and keep others some.

Let's say when I update the *"city1"* to *"city2"* and *"town1"* to *"town2"* on **textInput** others set empty. But others are supposed to stay as *"neighborhood1" "street1"*.

I am really new at React Native. Thank you for your answers.